# Does Docker stop take of care of stopping gossip and drain?

Tags: cassandra, shutdown

We have a setup where we have 3 cassandra nodes running as a cluster. We are using cassandra docker container with cassandra version 4.1.3.

So, in this scenario what happens when one of the node receives docker stop command?

Are we going to stop gossiping and drain the data before that node fully shutdown?

Is cassandra 4.1.3 internally handling the graceful shutdown (stop gossip and drain before shutdown)?

If not, is it not creating loss of data from that node?

Answer (score 1):

When stopping a container with the `docker stop` command, Docker sends a `TERM` signal to the main process in the container then after a grace period (usually 30 seconds), a `KILL` signal.

This sends an interrupt to Cassandra to shutdown gracefully, similar to sending a `KILL` signal to the Cassandra process. As one would expect, stopping a Cassandra container does not lead to data loss.

Note however that a regular shutdown does not initiate a `nodetool drain` so the commitlogs are replayed the next time the container is started.

For more info, see [the `stop` command in the official Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_stop/). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Erick .. this is useful info. We are looking of how cassandra 4.1.3 behaves when it receives TERM of KILL signal. Is Cassandra process internally handling draining of data and stoping of gossips when it receives TERM or KILL signal?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, a regular shutdown does not include `nodetool drain`. Forcing a memtable flush with `drain` is a manual process. Cheers!